# How to enable a UIButton if a textfield is not empty?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm having a problem with my UITextField and three UIButtons.
I want to disable the buttons when the UITextfield is empty and re-enable when it has text on it. I already tried this:

```
- (IBAction)validateFields:(id)sender {



    NSString *trimName = [URLToTrim stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    if (trimName.length >0)

    {
        trim.enabled = 1;
        trim2.enabled = 1;
        trim3.enabled =1;
        // proceed with your inserting values

    }


}
```

And this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
if([URLToTrim.text isEqualToString: @""]){  
    trim.hidden = YES;  
    trim2.hidden = YES;
    trim3.hidden = YES;

} else {  
    trim.hidden = NO;  
    trim2.hidden = NO;
    trim3.hidden = NO;   
}
```

and lastly, this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    if ([URLToTrim.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        trim.enabled = 0;
        trim2.enabled= 0;
        trim3.enabled = 0;
    }
```

But with the first one the app crashes when writing and with the second one the buttons aren't being re-enabled. Thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: my guess: add `.text` to `URLToTrim` in the first method. I guess `URLToTrim` is a UITextField? Because you are using .text in the `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: I wrote `- (IBAction)validateFields:(id)sender
{

 
    // On every press we're going to run through all the fields and get their length values. If any of them equal nil we will set our bool to NO.
 if (URLToTrim.text.length >0)
   
  {
   trim.enabled = 1;
   trim2.enabled = 1;
   trim3.enabled =1;
   // proceed with your inserting values
   
  }

    
}` but it still crashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems URLToTrim is a UITextField? The problem in the first is that you're calling `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:` on the text field itself, instead of the value of the text field. You do it right in the other two, using `URLToTrim.text`.

The problem with the second is that `viewDidLoad` is only called when the view is first loaded, so it never gets called again to re-enable the buttons. You want to do that code in one of the methods of your UITextFieldDelegate (which may already be your same view controller), probably `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` although `textFieldShouldEndEditing:`/`textFieldDidEndEditing:` could work if you only want the buttons to be updated when you finish editing.

Comment: I used `- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (URLToTrim.text.length < 1)
    {
        [trim setEnabled:NO];
  [trim2 setEnabled:NO];
  [trim3 setEnabled:NO];// return NO to not change text
    }
}` and seems to work but I can write on the UITextFiel (URLToTrim) :(

Comment: @zad0xsis: You need to return YES from that method, or the characters will not be inserted. Also, you have to take into account the changes that will be made, with something like `NSString *newtext = [URLToTrim.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string]; if (newtext.length < 1) { ... }`